# C# VSTO Access Sheet Control from Form

Tags: c#, controls, vsto

I have created a VSTO workbook with a textbox control, say textbox1. I have also created a form with a button, button1. How do I pass information from from a form to a sheet if the button is pressed?

```
public partial class frmInput: Form
{

    public frmInput()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sheet1.textbox1.text="Test"; //Gives me error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,  I found the answer to my question, I need to add Globals:

public partial class frmInput: Form
{

```
public frmInput()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Globals.sheet1.textbox1.text="Test"; //I was missing Globals
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to read more about Interop\VSTO and a bit more on WinForms\C# as well. This will save you time. I imagine you want something like -

```
string text = YourTextBox.Text;
```

Then, get instance of activesheet\cell like

```
using Workbook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Worksheet ws = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
Excel.Range activeCell = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveCell;
```

And insert text in activecell or sheet.

Comment: I am interested in inserting the text in the textbox not into the cell. The textbox is a vsto control floating ontop of a worksheet. What you have shown only creates a new instance of a cell / sheet.

Comment: Clearly I should have read the question minutely. Never mind.